# ANDROID: Update data in another activity in Master Detail Flow Layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, master-detail

I've searched for a solution for my question all over the internet but I haven't been able to find one and I hope you can help me out

I am trying to create a master detail flow application in android with 2 activities and the second activity contains a fragment. Can anyone please tell me how I can simultaneously update the value in the MainActivity() when I make a change in the fragment's EditText field? I have tried using an Intent but when the 2 activities are side by side that doesnt seem to work well.

[Screenshot of Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHmml.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Master detail flow uses one Fragment and two activities. The documentation example is here and doesn't use Intents. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are in a context as follows:

> When A happens, it triggers B

As a result, I suggest you to use [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/) library in your project.

The installation is easy. First, add the following code in your **build.gradle** file:

```java
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Second, let's see what we are going to add in our codes.

In the **Fragment** which you wanted to make changes:

```
/* When A happens */
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // complete entering the content, update it
    EventBus.getDefault.post(MyUpdateEvent(myContent));
});
```

Create your custom class **MyUpdateEven**:

```
public class MyUpdateEvent{
  private String myContent;

  public MyUpdateEvent(String myContent) {
    this.myContent = myContent;
  }

  public String getUpdateContent() {
    return myContent;
  }

}
```

In the **Activity** you wanted to update:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EventBus.getDefault.register(this); // add this code to monitor the update


      }

      /* It triggers B */
      @Subscribe // don't forget to add @Subscribe
      public void onEvent(MyUpdateEvent event){ 
        // this is your custom method

        myTextView.setText(event.getUpdateContent()); // do your update

      }

      @Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
          super.onDestroy();
          EventBus.getDefault.unregister(this); // when you leave this lifecycle, cancel the monitoring
      }
}
```

EventBus is a good library that I've been used a lot in my projects.
I think it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a interface.

```
public interface OnEditActivity {
    public void onEdit(ActivityObject activityObject, boolean isEditing);
 }
```

And on your another class for example **DetailActivity**, then you have to override the method **onEdit** that you created in your interface:

```
 public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnEditActivity{

 //IN HERE --- Create method.

  @Override
  public void onEdit(ActivityObject activityObject, boolean isEditing) {
    if(isEditing){
        displayView(activityObject,true);
    }else{
        displayView(activityObject,false);
    }
  }

}
```

And in your EditFragment for example will look like this:

```
public class EditFragment extends Fragment{

      //Define your interface in your fragment
      private OnEditActivity onEditActivity;

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_activity, container, false);
        return v;
    }

   public void onAttach(Activity a) {
     super.onAttach(a);
     onEditActivity =(OnEditActivity) a;
   }
}
```

And if you want to call **onEdit** method just call:

```
  onEditActivity.onEdit(activityObjectNew,false)
```

I hope this help you !